# What is the latest greatest way to move data between controls/queries and presentation elements

Tags: wpf, datagrid, master-detail

I have several combobox choices which a user can select from on a WPF window. Each of those compbo boxes are bound to different tables through EDMX. The combos do not bind to eachother.

I'm looking for a master/detail functionality. When a user selects anyone of the combobox selections(master) a query results(details) built from the selection(parameter) should be displayed in a datagrid section of the window.

The datagrid is NOT explicitly defined as it will contain different data depending on which combobox was selected from. So for the datagrid I'm using:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Height="167" Name="stackPanel4" VerticalAlignment="Top" DataContext="{StaticResource tbl_MyGenericDataGridViewSource}">
            <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" Height="166" Name="dataGrid1" Width="760" ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
</StackPanel>
```

What is the best data cache between the query results and the datagrid?
Should I be using a dataset?

This would be something I can bind to the datagrid on a combobox selection event or query return event.I want to do this taking advantage of Framework 4.0 WPF wizardry.

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing of EDMX.  But to do this, I'd create a simple view model class that exposed `ParentDataView`, `ChildDataView`, and `Text` properties, populate a collection of them, and then do something like this:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="selectTable" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding {StaticResource TableCollection}"             
          DisplayMemberPath="Text"/>
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=selectTable, Path=SelectedItem.ParentDataView}"/>
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=selectTable, Path=SelectedItem.ChildDataView}"/>
```

You could probably also just bind to a collection of `DataTable` objects, and set the binding on the child data grid's `ItemsSource` to a path like `SelectedItem.ChildRelations[0].ChildTable`, but then you'd be kind of screwed in the case where the table had multiple child relations and you didn't want to use the first one.

Also, creating `DataView`s in your view model class gives you an easy path to implementing sorting and filtering commands when the time comes.